# CSS: How can I center text despite a floating element beside it?

Tags: css, centering

Basically, I want to center text, ignoring any floating sibling elements.

At first, I thought this wouldn't be a problem, as I was under the impression that a floating element did not take from the width of any sibling elements.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cD657/) (I want the red text to be at the center of the blue box, despite the green text)

How is this best achieved?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't. If it were centered within the parent box, then the float would overlap the content at some point, which would be defeating the point of the float. There are two approaches you can use here. If you know the width of the float, you can apply an equal negative right margin. Otherwise, you can absolutely position the element [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/cD657/2/).

Comment: The only other option of which I can think is to make an identically sized object (invisible `div`, for instance) and float it to the opposite side of the parent container (containing other annoying float). It's better than using a margin to balance the centering because the floated object will affect text centering even if not in the same container as the text. Thoughts? Works great for me.

Comment: I liked your idea: Otherwise, you can absolutely position the element like this.

Comment: yes, positioning an absolute inside relative does just the trick

Comment: @Slink Your balancing-invisible-div idea worked great for me... would upvote if you made it an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a link to a working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/cD657/3/

(in your example, you opened a `<span>`, and closed it with `</div>`)

I made it a div and gave it `margin: 0px auto;` and a width.   -seemed to do the trick

Comment: But when you don't have a fixed width? Basically you cannot do this when you don't know the width of either one of the elements: the floated one or the text you want to center. I just ran into this issue now and searched for a solution, with no luck. I have a button and a text, both in the same DIV. I want the button to be aligned to the left, and the text to the center of the parent (the DIV). I tried with absolute positioning on the button and text-align:center on the parent div and it worked but then when the text is bigger, it will go behind the button :(

Answer (score 0):

You can keep as you have it but just adding padding on the opposite side with the same pixel value as the width of the floating element.

```
.parent{        
    text-align: center;
}
.centered.element{
     padding-left: [width of floating element]px;
}

.floating.element{
     float: left;
}
```

To find the width easily just use `Developer Tools` in any modern browser to `Inspect` the element.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cD657/369/

**Note:** This may not work if the centered element has an assigned `background` color.